# Adding functions to object parameters

Tags: javascript

I have around 50 objects like:

```
object[0].one = something;
object[0].two = else;
object[0].options = whatever;
```

Not sure how to describe it but they each have sub parameters. I was trying to add an additional parameter that I would add manually only to those I wanted too, like so:

```
object[15].condition = function() { if (something) { then do something; } } ;
//and then later on in a function do
if (this.condition) {
this.condition;
}
```

but I can't get it to work =( Is something like this possible? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: how does `object[15]` turn into `this`?

Comment: If you're calling a function that's a property of an object, you still have to add the parentheses. `this.condition()` instead of `this.condition`.

Comment: Amazing, bfuoco. I don't get why I don't at least try this stuff when I try at least everything else, for some reason I was just sure that wouldn't work..damnit. What a waste of time and a question, sorry for the trouble. Thanks so much, would have chose this as the best answer if it wasn't a comment, thanks again.

Comment: @Musa a little surprised you have 35k rep and are asking me that, I mean no offense at all. My objects are divs and they have a .onmousedown to call a function. using this, works in that function.

Comment: 35k rep doesn't give you psychic powers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (this.condition) {
  this.condition();
}
```